# How to retrieve all data from table if column value providing null value?

Tags: mysql

How to write a query:

If country = '    ' I need to display all data in table.
If country='algeria', it will display the particular data.
I need both queries in a single query.

I am getting result, but without providing variable how to write query...

```
declare @country1 varchar(30)
set @country1 = 'asd'

SELECT country_id, country
FROM   country
WHERE  
(
    (@country1  = '') 
    OR 
    (@country1 != '' AND country.country= @country1)
);
```

[image: Query and data]

with out  taking any  extra variable i need to  write query.
there@country1

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job.

```
DECLARE @country1 varchar(30)
SET @country1 = 'asd'

SELECT country_id, country
FROM   country
WHERE country.country LIKE IF(@country = '', '%', @country);
```

The IF statement works like this : IF(condition, ifverifiedcondition, else);

Comment: i don't want  to declare @country1 varchar(30)

Comment: without  declare @country1 varchar(30).  is it possible to write query?

Comment: So I don't understand what you really want as result... Can you edit your question with what you exactly have as data and what you exactly want as result ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try it.

```
DECLARE @country1 varchar(30)
SET @country1 = 'asd'

SELECT country_id, country
FROM   country
WHERE country.country LIKE IF(@country Is Null, '%', @country);
```

Is Null used when not insert data in country field

```
IF @country Is Null
Begin
Select country_id,country
from country
End
ELSE IF @country Is Not Null
Begin
Select country_id,country
from country
where country.country ='abc'
End
```